# Convert Duration Column to integer value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, datetime, time

I have a pandas dataframe with a duration column, they're currently of the object type with entries like 01:15:12 which means 1 hour and 15 minutes and 12 seconds, not the time. I want to strip the seconds off and convert these values to 1.25 because 15 minutes/60 minutes in an hour is .25 hours. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Parse to timedelta, take the total_seconds and divide by 3600 to get fractional hours. If you need more specific advice, please provide a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pandas.to_timedelta`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html):

```
pd.to_timedelta(df['COLUMN']).dt.floor('T').dt.total_seconds()/3600
```